# How to Move the sprite with conditions and constrains

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am having 32 sprite in my scene  I had arranged my sprite like this

```
                 o   o   o

                 o   o   o

       o    o    o   o   o    o    o

       o    o    o   .   o    o    o 

       o    o    o   o   o    o    o

                 o   o   o

                 o   o   o
```

o ---> MovingBall
  . ---> empty hole

When I move move one sprite to empty hole, the middle sprite will be removed and my sprite and hole should be interchanged, like this.

```
o  o  . ----->  . . o
```

possible ways:

```
    |            |         |            |          |            |           |
o   |            |    .    |            |   o      |         .  |  .        |       .
o   |   o  o  .  |    o    |  .  o  o   |     o    |       o    |    o      |     o
.   |            |    o    |            |       .  |    o       |      o    |  o
    |            |         |            |          |            |           |
```

Totally 8 possibility to move the sprite.

Can anyone help me how to do this
and what should I want to change in my code?

My coding is here

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ 
UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];


if(movingBall)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<32; i++)
    {
        CCSprite *currentSprite = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:i];

        if(CGRectContainsPoint([currentSprite boundingBox],location))
        {
            // get moving sprite touched

            if(movingBall.position.x == hole.position.x+(2*75) || movingBall.position.x == hole.position.x-(2*75) || movingBall.position.y == hole.position.y+(2*75) || movingBall.position.y == hole.position.y -(2*75))
            {
                movingBall = (CCSprite *)currentSprite;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
  }
 }
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];
location=[self convertToNodeSpace:location];

if(!movingBall)
{
    return;
}


movingBall.position = location;

for(int i = 0; i<32; i++)
{
    CCSprite *currentSprite = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:i];

    if(CGRectIntersectsRect([movingBall boundingBox],[currentSprite boundingBox]))
    {
        // current sprite touched
        if(currentSprite.tag == hole.tag)
        {
            movingBall.position = hole.position;

            [self removeChild:currentSprite];
            break;
        }

    }
}}

-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if(!movingBall)
{
    return;
}

movingBall = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(I don't know this programming language so this is purely an algorithmic perspective)

First, compute the starting and ending locations that the user is attempting to move a ball from and to. If the move is not from a filled space, reject. If the move is not to an empty space, reject.

Second, calculate the movement of the ball - xDelta = xEnd - xStart, yDelta = yEnd - yStart. For the movement to be valid, one of the two must be true:

- either abs(xDelta) or abs(yDelta) == 2, and the other == 0.
- abs(xDelta) == 2 and abs(yDelta) == 2.

If neither is true, reject.

Finally, calculate the mid point cell. xMid = xStart + xDelta/2, yMid = yStart + yDelta/2. If this is filled with a ball, perform the move by emptying xStart,yStart, emptying xMid,yMid and filling xEnd,yEnd. If it is not filled with a ball, reject.

Comment: Can you help me with code  please,Because i am beginner in cocos2d.

Comment: I do not know any cocos2d.

Comment: can you elabrate your concept briefly. Is there any other possible way to do this.

Comment: Of course there are other ways to do it :) This is just how I would start. I am not giving you code though since I do not know cocos2d :)

Comment: Ok tell me that another way